# How do I change the x-axis labels?

Tags: r, plot

This is the code that I used to try and get the output in the attached:

```
fun_plot5 <- function(ycol, ylab, xcol, data) {
  xx3 <- paste(ycol, xcol, sep = "~")
  xx3 <- as.formula(xx3)
  plotmeans(xx3, data = get_proposer,
            xlab = "Gender", ylab = ylab,
            main = "Mean Plot with 95% CI")
}

y_cols6 <- names(get_proposer[24:29])

y_lab6 <- c("Actual Offer (by A)", "Actual Amount Transferred to Partner (Bot)", "Actual Payoff (for A)", "Practice Offer (by A)", "Pradtice Amount Transferred to Partner (Bot)", "Practice Payoff (for A)")

old_par4 <- par(mfrow = c(3,3))
mapply(fun_plot5, y_cols6, y_lab6, 
       MoreArgs = list(
         xcol = "gender",
         data = get_proposer
       ))
```

[image]

I'm trying to change the x-axis values (for all plots) from 1 and 2, to "Male" and "Female", respectively. I tried including this line of code at the end of the code above, but I was still not able to get the outcome I want.

```
fun_plot5 +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Male", "Female"))
```

When I added this line to one of my other plots that used ggplot, it worked. But it didn't work for the current plot, in attached. How should I go about with this?

Many thanks!

**Updated with Data**

```
# A tibble: 31 x 10
   similar_task   age gender income actual_offer actual_payoff actual_partner_transfer practice_partner_transfer practice_offer practice_payoff
          <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>                   <dbl>                     <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
 1            5    29      1      4           40           126                      66                        48             30             118
 2            3    36      1      4          100           273                     273                       180            100             180
 3            5    39      2      2            0           100                       0                         0              0             100
 4            3    25      1      7          100             6                       6                       195            100             195
 5            3    28      2      7           25            99                      24                        84             50             134
 6            2    45      2      5           80            29                       9                        42            100              42
 7            3    30      1      6          100            45                      45                       123            100             123
 8            5    37      1      3            0           100                       0                         0              0             100
 9            2    38      2      2           25            99                      24                        63             25             138
10            1    25      1      1          100           183                     183                       285            100             285
# ... with 21 more rows
```

The columns that I used in my plots (in attached) can be found in the last few columns in the data, from "actual_offer" to "practice_payoff" (or, columns 24:29 in the entire dataset).

Comment: You are using base R plotting tools, and `scale_x_discrete()` is from the `ggplot2` package. The two cannot be combined.

Comment: Thanks Phil, in this case, based on my current code, how should I change the x-axis labels?

Comment: Try `axis(1, labels = c("Male", "Female"))`

Comment: Hi Phil, I've tried that, but it doesn't work. Where specifically should I place this line of code? (in reference to the code that I've provided. Thanks.

Comment: Should be later, but I don't know where the `plotmeans()` function comes from, and I'm not even that well-versed in base R plotting anyway.

Comment: From which package is `plotmeans` function from? Can you make this post reproducible by adding data?

Comment: Hi Ronak, `plotmeans`  function is from the {gplots} package. I've also edited the post to include the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the plotmeans documentation the legends argument is defined as the vector containing strings to label the groups. What happens when you try legends=c("Male, "Female") within your plotmeans call?